# not getting span id after update panel refresh

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tax9n/6/)

my table which is in  update panel after update panel refresh
i m not getting span id.

```
$(".csstablelisttd").live('mousedown', function (e)
                {
                    clearFields();

                    //This line gets the index of the first clicked row.
                    lastRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;

                    var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
                    colIndex = $(e.target).closest('td').index();
    var id =$('.csstextheader').find('td').eq(colIndex).find('span').attr('id');

});
<table id="contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment" cellspacing="1" width="100%" bgcolor="#cccccc">
        <tr Class="csstextheader">
            <td class="csstextheader" width="70px">
                                        </td>
            <td class="csstextheader" width="70px">
                                            <b>Time Slot&nbsp;</b>
                                        </td>
            <td ID="9"><span id=9>CR (CR1)</span></td>
            <td ID="10"><span id=10>ES (ES1)</span></td>
            <td ID="11"><span id=11>MR (MR1)</span></td>
            <td ID="13"><span id=13>US (US1)</span></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ID's in a page must be unique

Comment: yes.....................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector isn't precise enough. Use

```
$('tr.csstextheader').find('td').eq(colIndex).find('span').attr('id')
```

---

Note that you could have used

```
<th...
```

instead of

```
<td class="csstextheader"...
```

And then your code would have been

```
$('th').eq(colIndex).find('span').attr('id')
```